# Wondering why a Jira Cloud plugin with page module fails to install with 'project_type' condition set?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I am working on a plugin for Jira Cloud and am trying to add a new page specific to a given project.  Based on the information for conditions on the "Pages" documentation https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/modules/page/ I should be able to use the Jira condition `project_type`, however, when I add it to my descriptor file like this

```
"conditions": [
  {
    "condition": "user_is_logged_in"
  },
  {
    "condition": "project_type",
    "params" : {
      "projectTypeKey": "service_desk"
    }
  }
]
```

it fails to install with the error

> Installation failed. The app includes a Page module with an unsupported condition (project_type).

My question is, did I miss something about how to add conditions, or about how to use the page conditions, or is it really not allowing what is listed in the documentation?

I posted this question on Atlassian's forum but have not gotten a response, so I'm trying here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it will fail if you use it for `generalPages` module, which makes sense due to that page not being project related per se. However, it should work with `jiraProjectPages`. I verified it with this module and it works

```
  "jiraProjectPages": [
{
  "url": "/general-page.html",
  "iconUrl": "/logo-url-or-inline-svg",
  "weight": 100,
  "name": {
    "value": "My Project Page"
  },
  "key": "my-project-page",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "condition": "project_type",
      "invert": true,
      "params": {
        "projectTypeKey": "business"
      }
    }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: Thank you!! Worked perfectly.  I knew I was missing something but I had been at it for hours and just couldn't see it anymore.